# Why do we use `#include "stdafx.h"` instead of `#include <stdafx.h>`?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, header-files, directive

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594/1245120), it is said that:

> For `#include "filename"` the preprocessor searches in the same
>   directory as the file containing the directive. This method is
>   normally used to include programmer-defined header files.
>
> For `#include <filename>` the preprocessor searches in an implementation
>   dependent manner, normally in search directories pre-designated by the
>   compiler/IDE. This method is normally used to include standard library
>   header files.

While [this wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h) suggests that `stdafx.h` is an header file pre-designed by `visual studio IDE`

> stdafx.h is a file, generated by Microsoft Visual Studio IDE wizards,
>   that describes both standard system and project specific include files
>   that are used frequently but hardly ever change.
>
> Compatible compilers (for example, Visual C++ 6.0 and newer) will
>   precompile this file to reduce overall compile times. Visual C++ will
>   not compile anything before the #include "stdafx.h" in the source
>   file, unless the compile option /Yu'stdafx.h' is unchecked (by
>   default); it assumes all code in the source up to and including that
>   line is already compiled.
>
> The AFX in stdafx.h stands for Application Framework eXtensions. AFX
>   was the original abbreviation for the Microsoft Foundation Classes
>   (MFC). While the name stdafx.h is used by default, projects may
>   specify an alternative name.

Then

**Why do we use #include `"stdafx.h"` instead of `#include <stdafx.h>` ?**

Comment: Perhaps **where** Visual Studio default-generates that header may be of some assistance in answering your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `stdafx.h`, `stdafx.cpp` pair is generated by VS from a template.  It resides in the same directory the rest of the files end up.  You will probably end up altering it specifically for your project.  So we use `""` instead of `<>` for exactly the reason that it's in the same directory as your first quote describes.

Comment: OK, I see `stdafx.obj`, `stdafx.h`, `stdafx.cpp` in the `...\testMEX\testMEX\Debug` and `...\testMEX\testMEX` where `testMEX` is the name of my console application project

Comment: so you mean 1- the files `stdafx.h`, `stdafx.cpp`, `handler_stdafx.h`, `handler_stdafx.cpp` in different subfolders `(.NET, ATL, Generic, MFC)` of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\AppWiz` 2- the files `Stdafx.h`, `StdAfx.h`, `Stdafx.cpp`, `StdAfx.cpp`in different parts of the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensibility Projects` 3- the files `stdafx.h`, `stdafx.cpp` in different subfolders `(include, lib, src)` of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc` directory 4- the files `stdafx.h`,

Comment: `stdafx.cpp` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump` directory in my `Win7x64` machine are all templates. And when we start a new project in `Visual Studio 2010` a special `stdafx.h` file is created for that based on the type of the projects and using these templates?

Comment: I've included #include "stdafx.h" in my code but I'm getting the errors 'cannot open source file "stdafx.h"' and 'Cannot include file: "stdafx.h": No such file or directory. Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Because `stdafx.h` is different for each project. As you quoted, `#include ""` searches the path of the current project, and this is where `stdafx.h` is located.

Using `#include <stdafx.h>` would be a ***huge*** mistake, because it would have to be in the library path (where all the standard library headers are located). This would mean that you shouldn't modify it, or that it always stays the same, but it's never the same for different projects.

So even though it is generated by Visual Studio, it is specific to the project, not to all projects.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a given include file name.h, the syntax `#include <name>` is reserved for the [standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library), while `#include "name.h"` is used for user-defined files. There, 'user' could mean any developer implementing non-standard features, say for a particular compiler package.

Accordingly, the preprocessor searches for the include files following the suitable paths specified by the system settings in place. Note not only the difference between brackets and quotes, but also the different usage of the *.h extension.